# Can a TargetControlID of a PopUp use the Button of a GridView?

Tags: asp.net, button, gridview, modalpopupextender

I have a `Button` with `id=btnSend` that named "Send" in `GridView`.

I have a `ModalPopUpExtender id="SendPopUp"` and `TargetControlID="btnSend"`

and

```
<asp:Panel id="SendPanel">
```

I get the error as

> System.InvalidOperationException: The TargetControlID of '
>   SendPopUp'is not valid. A control with ID 'btnSend' could not be
>   found.

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You need to add the Click event of button then from code behind file you can show model popup by simply write code in button click event

modal.show()
```

For your reference i am providing you complete code as follow.
I hope it will help you.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .modalBackground
    {
    background-color: Gray;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 10000;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvdetails" DataKeyNames="UserId" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn" ImageUrl="~/Edit.jpg" runat="server" Width="25" Height="25" onclick="imgbtn_Click" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Designation" HeaderText="Designation" />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:Label ID="lblresult" runat="server"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" style="display:none" />
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" PopupControlID="pnlpopup"
    CancelControlID="btnCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="269px" Width="400px" style="display:none">
    <table width="100%" style="border:Solid 3px #D55500; width:100%; height:100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr style="background-color:#D55500">
    <td colspan="2" style=" height:10%; color:White; font-weight:bold; font-size:larger" align="center">User Details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" style=" width:45%">
    UserId:
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">
    UserName:
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:Label ID="lblusername" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">
    FirstName:
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfname" runat="server"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">
    LastName:
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtlname" runat="server"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">
    City:
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">
    Designation:
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesg" runat="server"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Text="Update" onclick="btnUpdate_Click"/>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Code Behind file

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(!IsPostBack)
{
BindGridData();
}
}
protected void BindGridData()
{
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Employee_Details", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
gvdetails.DataSource = dt;
gvdetails.DataBind();
}
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Employee_Details set FirstName=@FirstName,LastName=@LastName, City=@City,Designation=@Designation where UserId=@UserId", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtfname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtlname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtCity.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", txtDesg.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Convert.ToInt32(lblID.Text));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
lblresult.Text = lblusername.Text + " Details Updated Successfully";
lblresult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
BindGridData();
}
protected void imgbtn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
ImageButton btndetails = sender as ImageButton;
GridViewRow gvrow = (GridViewRow)btndetails.NamingContainer;
lblID.Text = gvdetails.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
lblusername.Text = gvrow.Cells[1].Text;
txtfname.Text = gvrow.Cells[2].Text;
txtlname.Text = gvrow.Cells[3].Text;
txtCity.Text = gvrow.Cells[4].Text;
txtDesg.Text = gvrow.Cells[5].Text;
this.ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since your panel if outside of the gridview it wont work this way. add a hiddenfield and set the targetcontrolid to that field. Next in the button click of the gridview use modalpopup.show();

Comment: thank you for your reply. Could you please help me out with some simple example ?